# Add a OneNote template to a document set as default content

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, onenote

using powershell, I'm trying to upload a certain OneNote template to a Document Set with specific contenttypes. I believe the code is working: the document is indeed added to the SharePoint admin GUI, and upon creation of a Document Set, the OneNote file is added to the document set.

Code:

```
$cType = Get-PnPContentType -Identity "Meeting Tracker"
[byte[]]$bytes = Get-Content -Path "./assets/Meetings.one" -AsByteStream -Raw
Write-Host "        Adding default document 'Meetings section' to Document Set template..."
$DocSet.DefaultDocuments.Add( "Meetings.one", $cType.Id, $bytes ) | Out-Null
$DocSet.Update( $True ) | Out-Null
Invoke-PnPQuery | Out-Null
```

The problem is that, when I open that newly created OneNote section through the browser, I always get prompted that the file needs converting to the 2010-2016 format. This is however a new file, created in OneNote 2016 (desktop).

I have tried exporting the file as a .onepkg and upload that to the Document Set, but such a file cannot be opened in the browser and needs to be downloaded.

I have also tried dragging-and-dropping the exported file to the Document Set, and that also triggers the same behavior.

The file I am trying to set as default content just contains 1 single page with a few tables, and that page is set as the default page template inside the 'Meetings' section.

Any ideas?